# Able to fetch text with their locations from an image...How can I form sentence?

Tags: javascript, python, image-processing, ocr, image-conversion

I am using online library and able to fetch words from an image with their locations.

Now I want to form sentences exactly like which are in image.

Any idea how can I do that?

Earlier i used the distance between two words and if there are pretty close then it means it is a part of a sentence but this approach is not working fine
Please help

This is the json I am receiving I have...

"WordText": "Word 1",
                                "Left": 106,
                                "Top": 91,
                                "Height": 9,
                                "Width": 11
                                },
                                {
                                "WordText": "Word 2",
                                "Left": 121,
                                "Top": 90,
                                "Height": 13,
                                "Width": 51
                                }
                                .
                                .
                                .
                                More Words

Answer (score 0):

I don't if I am understanding your problem correctly, but I'm assuming each dictionary in your json is giving you the coordinates for a word.

My approach would be to first find the difference in pixels for the space between any 2 words, and you use this value to detect the sequence of words.

For example:
`img1 = {'coordinates': 'information'}`
`img2 = {'coordinates': 'information'}`
`space_value = 10  # for example`

`if img1['Height'] == img2['Height'] and (img1['Left'] + img1['Width'] + space_value) == img2['Left']:`
    `next_word = True`

Comment: Did the same thing but it is not giving satisfactory results. Some cases it fails miserably like a sentence in multiple lines in short area

Comment: Any library or another approach someone can suggest ?

Comment: You should attempt to detect when a new line is required in a sentence, using a similar approach.